# Using ffmpeg to cut up video into smaller video with exactly 30 frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frames

I need to cut a video with >300 frames into ten videos, where the first video comprises the first 30 frames, the second video comprises frames from 31 to 60 and so on.

Comment: Might I suggest you ask this at http://superuser.com?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Done - https://superuser.com/questions/1309493/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video-into-smaller-video-with-exactly-30-frames. Thanks